# Remove WebDAVModule from startup.cs asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config, startup, devextreme

IIS Server gives "Method Not Found Error". After Exploring Google, I got that WebDAVModule should be removed in web config file.
Every time i publish my Project, i have to add this
`<modules> <remove name="WebDAVModule" /> </modules>`
in Webconfig

Please suggest me how do i add this in Startup.cs or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `web.config` file to your project, like bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways

**Remove from IIS model**

Go to your site in IIS
Click "Modules"
Remove WebDAVModule
Restart site (might not be needed)

[image]

**Remove from windows features**

[image: Turn windows features on or off]